# How do I get this PFET to switch off when G=5V (high)

Tags: mosfet, switches

What am I missing (and why) to allow this PFET to switch on and off? I'm new to this but am learning. The circuit is part of a larger schematic I am working on. Once I get this working I can insert it and finish the schematic. Any lessons would be of enormous value added to schematics help to me. I don't want just the answer, I want the reason for the answer, so I can grasp this concept. YouTube tutorials only help so much...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh9v7h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is there a reason for using a PFET and doing high side switching? The circuit could be simpler with an N-channel mosfet

Comment: this circuit is not actually driving an LED but the gate of an NFET to switch a cap in and out of a circuit. The entire circuit is designed to switch 2 fets in and out of a circuit with only a single logic level of a micro.I can post the whole schematic.

Comment: Vg by itself doesn't help you to understand the problem. Ask yourself what Vgs is, because that's what your PFET sees.

Comment: should be ~15v?

Comment: Think about what Vgs would need to be to turn off the PMOS.

Comment: As i understand it, the gate in reference to the source needs to be withing 1v

Comment: According to the datasheet, the Vgs(th) is between -2V and -4V, but you are on the right track now.  Imagine if the PMOS actually was off, what is the voltage at the source now (and how does it relate to the gate)?

Comment: oh...those arent the actual mosfets......I havent picked those out yet, just want the circuit to function. I have been given this 'simple' task to broaden my knowledge. The engineer says that I am close but not quite there yet with this circuit

Comment: Fair enough.  Just think about what I am saying, you are almost there.

Comment: I need to have the Gate = Source when the micro sends out the 5v (high) signal. Does that mean the voltage at the Source terminal or the source voltage (vcc)

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is?  See my answer below.

Comment: Gate control signals are typically refrenced to GND, but when the MOSFET source pin is not also connected to ground, that means the signal source does not have the same reference that the MOSFET actually cares about since it only cares about gate-source voltage difference, not gate-gnd. So you need a circuit that takes te control signal and re-references it from gnd to source pin. "High-side gate drive" for NMOS is most often when you encounter this and searching that may give you ideas for your PMOS.

Comment: Do not fail to consider zener diodes in your solution should you need to produce strange supply voltages not referenced to GND, but powered from a ground referenced rail. Combined with pull up resistors and pull down transistors, the control signal can drive an excess voltage from the rails while the the zener to bleed off excess voltage from the rails so it appears referenced to thing other than gnd.

Comment: thank you, I'll consider that option also

Comment: Please don't change the question after asking it and getting an answer, if the answer solved your problem.  This confuses people who come and see the question later. (R5 wasn't in the original question, and R5 makes evildemonic's answer make no sense)

Comment: It is better to add UPDATE sections to the original post.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this circuit is that the PMOS M1 will never turn off.

PMOS needs the gate to be within a few volts of the source to turn off.  While on, you have a voltage divider consisting of R1 and R2, I am assuming, in an attempt to keep the source of M1 at around 5V (not the 15V you replied in a comment).  This works until you attempt to turn off the PMOS by bringing the gate up to 5V.  As the PMOS tries to turn off the channel between source and drain becomes resistive, raising the voltage on the source towards 20V.  You won't even be able to turn it off that much because once the source is 7V or higher, Vgs will be too big and keep the device conducting.

If the PMOS were somehow truly off, you would have 20V on the source and 5V on the gate.  i.e. it will always be at least partially on.

Comment: that is basically what my engineer told me was the issue.  I need to keep S at 5 to 6v when the G switches to 5v?

Comment: You got it.  This current circuit does not do that.

Comment: add a R between R1 and G

Comment: That could fix this problem (assuming you mean a resistor that goes from the junction between the source of M1 and R1 to ground).  It may bring up another, as it would affect the voltage available to the gate of M5.

Comment: i added it to the schematic

Comment: No, to ground, not the gate.  You are trying to create a resistor divider to keep the source under 6V.  Make the resistor 3.3kΩ.

Comment: Thank you for all the guidance, i updated the schematic

Comment: So as Vg reaches 5v the FET tries to turn off while the source tries to reach towards 20v,but the added voltage divider keeps that voltage at or around 5v thereby turning the fet off. Correct?

Comment: Exactly right. Hopefully you don't now have a problem turning on M4 and M5.

Comment: lets hope not. However engineer says it will technically work but that the leakage would be too high to implement.......smh

Comment: You could always add a NMOS between the clock and the PMOS as a low-side switch.  This way you could switch the gate on the PMOS with 20V and avoid this problem altogether.